# Ubuntu connects to wired connection, has DNS, works on local network, no Internet

Tags: networking, internet, wired

Just yeterday I built a system dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10, but today the Ubuntu install started having issues with networking (the Windows part is working perfectly).

The system recognizes that it's connected to a network when the ethernet cable is plugged in. When pinging google.com, it is able to resolve the IP address but isn't able to actually ping out. The same goes for 8.8.8.8 - can't reach the address. However, the computer does have a local IP address and is able to reach other resources on the local network (it's a university network, and it's able to connect to servers that are hosted on campus).

The gist of it is that it connects to the network with DNS and has local access, but can't reach out to the Internet in Ubuntu (but can in Windows). Any ideas what may be causing this / how to continue to diagnose?

EDIT 1: As requested, command outputs

ip a s output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:7d:f3:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 129.2.204.242/23 brd 129.2.205.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 3211sec preferred_lft 3211sec
    inet6 fe80::e62e:edbc:19cb:67d2/64 cope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip r s output

```
default via 129.2.204.1 dev enp0s31f6  proto static  metric 100
128.8.76.11 via 129.2.204.1 dev enp0s31f6  proto dhcp  metric 100
129.2.204.0/23 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src 129.2.204.242  metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6  scope link  metric 1000
```

ip n output

```
129.2.204.29 dev enp0s31f6 lladdr 54:ee:75:9c:2b:cc REACHABLE
129.2.204.1 dev enp0s31f6 lladdr 00:08:e3:ff:fc:50 STALE
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't have a default gateway set. Type `route -n` and if you have a default gateway set, you should see an entry similar to:

```
0.0.0.0         128.100.13.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

In the above example, 128.100.13.254 is my default gateway, which is accessible via my eth1 interface.

If you don't have a default gateway set, and you know what its IP is, you can add it by issuing the command:

```
sudo route add default gw YOUR_GW_IP_HERE
```

Comment: I just checked again (did earlier as well) and I do have a default gateway which is reachable by ping. Aside from the gateway address itself and the name of the interface (which lines up with the active network interface's name, which is enp0s31f), my line looks exactly the same as the one you posted.

Comment: Is some firewall running on? Edit your question with `ip a s ` , `ip r s`  and `ip n`.

Comment: I just edited my post with those command outputs.