# Wired connection is up but internet does not work

Tags: networking

I am working on a Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits. Four days ago, internet stopped working for no reason. As it was very late on a friday, I decided to go home early and hope it would be solved on monday, as the office network sometimes does this kind of things.

The wired connection icon shows a working connection, but if I try to ping google DNS servers (4.4.4.4) I get a 100% packet loss. I can ping the office gateway, but nothing more.

Restarting the network-manager does not solve the issue and just gives me a new IP each time.

Doing: `nslookup google.de`:

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53
d
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.de
Address 216.58.208.131
```

Output of `route`

```
default         gateway 0.0.0.0         UG  100  0  0  enp0s25
10.155.24.0     *       255.255.248.0   U   100  0  0  enp0s25
da1csdc11000003 gateway 255.255.255.255 UGH 100  0  0  enp0s25
link-local      *       255.255.0.0     U   1000 0  0  enp0s25
```

And output of `ip n`:

```
10.155.24.254 dev enp0s25 lladdr 00:00:5e:00:01:01 DELAY
```

Output of `netstat -rn`

```
0.0.0.0         10.155.24.254 0.0.0.0         UG  0  0  0 enp0s25
10.155.24.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.248.0   U   0  0  0 enp0s25
10.243.75.135   10.155.24.254 255.255.255.255 UGH 0  0  0 enp0s25
169.254.0.0     20.0.0.0      255.255.0.0     U   0  0  0  enp0s25
```

Comment: So what does `cat /etc/resolv.conf` say? You also mistaken 8.8.8.8 is the google dns...  4.4.0.0 - 4.4.255.255 is owned by http://whois.arin.net/ui/ and no idea what 4.4.4.4 is used for atm.

Comment: You don't say, should we assume you already rebooted the router?

Comment: No I did not. I do not have access to the router.

Comment: @Ziazis: the file contents are:
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search emea.xxxxx.hub (where xxxx is the company I work)

Comment: So does pinging 8.8.8.8 work? What does `nslookup google.de` give you? Also what does `nslookup google.de 8.8.8.8` give you. Since your resolv.conf shows back to yourself this seems weird to me, what did you install before things stopped working?

Comment: I added the result of nslookup google.de. If I add the 8.8.8.8 the connection times out. Last thing I remember installing is Torch, a framework for Lua.

Comment: Can you post the results of a `traceroute 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: I do not have traceroute installed, and need internet to do so... :(

Comment: Your DNS is working fine, what you have an issue with is probably a default gateway issue, what does `route` print?

Comment: I added it to the question. Also, I found this: 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/880249/ubuntu-connects-to-wired-connection-has-dns-works-on-local-network-no-interne?rq=1

Which is exactly my issue, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the notes in `man resolvconf` and you'll see that you probably need to add some info to /etc/network/interfaces. Something like:

```
dns-nameserver [gatewayip]
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
dns-nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

And to make it work right away, vi /etc/resolv.conf and add:

```
nameserver [gatewayip]
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

Comment: It didn't work. I guess that I have to resolvconf -a [gatewayip] / 8.8.8.8 / 4.2.2.2, and it will update the /etc/resolv.conf file, but it just hangs in there for ever. 

Is there any command so I can restart all network configurations to default? I really don't understand anything that's happening or why, as it's been working flawlessly up until a week ago.

Comment: Try these: `netstat -rn`, `ping 8.8.8.8`, `wget -O - http://ipchicken.com 2>/dev/null | grep "^[0-9]"`,  `wget -O - http://104.25.113.262>/dev/null | grep "^[0-9]"`   -  netstat will show the numeric routing table, ping will let you know if you are getting outside, and the 2 wget's both go out to ipchicken, but the last doesn't need DNS. -- then post the results.

Comment: Edited the question with netstat -rn. Pings do not get outside of the network, but the domain name is solved (I can ping www.google.de and my local DNS gives me the IP). 

Both wgets get stuck at "Connecting to <IP/url>

Comment: Is there a reason for this static route?:  `10.243.75.135   10.155.24.254 255.255.255.255 UGH 0  0  0 enp0s25` - Also - are you aware of any VPN software that might be running? (they can cause unintentional routing through the VPN where there's no return path)

Comment: Sorry, the office closed for summer and I haven't read all this until now. No, there's not a reason for that route that I am aware off. I am not sure about the VPN, I haven't configured it, but I know here in the office there is some kind of it. How should I fix that static route?

Comment: You should be able to delete it for testing purposes using ''route delete 10.243.75.135''. Then if that gets things working, you either have to find the entry in /etc/network* or /etc/NetworkManager or some other script executing during boot that is adding the route and delete it.